# Do High-End CPUs Last Longer?

Tags: hardware-failure, overclocking, lifespan, logical-processor

The new Intel Skylake processors consume less electricity and run at cooler temperatures than their predecessors, the Broadwell processors (according to Intel ARK). Fortunately, Skylake processors still support overclocking (can be clocked to higher speeds). However, overclocking requires more electricity, and therefore generates more heat. Do high-end Skylake processors clocked at a base 4.0 GHz have a longer lifespan than lower-end Skylake processors overclocked to 4.0 GHz?

---

**EDITED: Added clarity**

Don't high-end CPUs handle simple tasks more easily (consume less energy and/or are more heat-resistant) than low-end CPUs? If this is confusing, here is an example: Let's say I run Overwatch on a high-end CPU and a low-end CPU (low-end CPU **overclocked** to 3.0 GHz and high-end CPU **based** at 3.0 GHz). Will the high-end CPU have a longer lifetime (degrade after a longer amount of time)?

Comment: I've never had a CPU fail, and I have a machine that's roughly a decade old in constant/consistant use.

Comment: Processors of a specific generation are identical except for minimal differences in the silicon and in most cases they are identical and made different by disabling features due the quality of the silicon after production.  In other words they come off the exact same silicon wafer.

Comment: High-end CPUs may have more stringent inspection requirements, and some low-end CPUs may be "rejects" from high-end lines with portions disabled. However, properly handled and cared for, you should not have to worry about the reliability of a given CPU if it is appropriately chose for its role.

Comment: By overclocking the CPU you are inviting a potential failure by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, CPUs do not fail on their own.  They do not have any moving parts to wear out, and should work indefinitely.

This doesnt mean that they do not fail.  Excessive heat can cause a processor to fail.  In your example, the two processors *should* have an equal lifespan, assuming the fan and heat sink in the overclocked CPU can transfer the heat away quickly. If for some reason, the heat builds up to high, the processor could burn out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very wide range to cover since we are talking about all CPU's and there are many different CPU types. Let's go even older such as the Haswell processors and the 4790k which was "high-end" 3 years ago. It doesn't make a difference if you have a low end Haswell processors going up against a high end Haswell. They are both the same architecture in which the degregation process will be about the same depending under how much you use it such as overclocking. But if we are talking different architectures it is too early to tell if it will last long or not because we are talking about years here and Skylake has only been out for about a little more than a 1 year. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

CPUs rarely fail. In all cases they are likely to last at least a decade.

I run hundreds of servers with all kinds of CPUs and the CPU never failed. These are usually high-end CPUs but I also made devices with Atom CPUs that are still running for more than a decade.

Usually power supplies fail if they get hot.

Heat is the main enemy of electronics.

Comment: I did not down-vote, but I am asking which lasts longer. In the case of long term MISSION-CRITICAL computing where failure is never an option (i.e. a hospital serving people from 1998 to now), this would be especially important.

Comment: For the medical industry the CPU is the smallest concern. There are MANY expensive accreditations that need to be passed for safety and EMI that are way more difficult to overcome. I am pretty sure any CPU would pass and it could work for a decade continuously.